Unable to see files and folders stored on Desktop
Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. After the upgradation, I am unable to see any files or folders on my Desktop. I could see that the files and folders exists  in the folder "Desktop".
I tried the solution suggested at Files in Desktop folder not showing on Desktop
But it did not work for me.
How can I fix this issue?
